# Cannot create nested network namespace

Tags: linux, ip, linux-networking, namespaces, network-namespace

Is seems that one is not able to create a network namespace from a network namespace. It results in "Error: Peer netns reference is invalid.".

Is this a bug or is there some kind of limitation that I am not aware of?

Below is my cmd trace of the error.

```
# ip netns add foo1
# ip netns exec foo1 ip netns add foo2
# ip netns
Error: Peer netns reference is invalid.
Error: Peer netns reference is invalid.
foo2
foo1
# ip netns exec foo2 /bin/bash
setting the network namespace "foo2" failed: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TL;DR: As weird as it seems, this is actually not a *network* namespace issue, but a *mount* namespace issue and is to be expected.

You should create all new "ip netns namespaces" (see later for the meaning), i.e. run all `ip netns add ...` commands from the initial (host) "ip netns namespace", not from inside an "ip netns namespace" having been entered with `ip netns exec ...`. As long as you don't *create* them you're then free to *switch* between them at will including nesting commands from one to an other, with `ip netns exec ...`.

Detailed explanation with step-by-step examples following...

---

`ip netns` is specialized on network namespaces, but to handle all features, has also to mingle with mount namespaces for two reasons (at least, that I know of):

- bind mounting `/etc/netns/FOO/SOMESERVICE` to `/etc/SOMESERVICE` to manage alternate service/daemon configurations

  A feature which can be handy to easily run some (network related) daemons in an other network namespace but beside this being still part of the "host". You can check my answer at UL on a question about it there: [Namespace management with ip netns (iproute2)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471122/namespace-management-with-ip-netns-iproute2/471214#471214). Its use requires the same treatment as the following feature, so I won't talk about it anymore.
- remounting `/sys` to expose new network namespace's network devices in its hierarchy

  This one is a mandatory feature. Example exposing the problem:

  From "initial host":

  ```
  # ip link add dev dummy9 type dummy
  # ip -br link show dummy9 
  dummy9           DOWN           f6:f6:48:9c:12:b9 <BROADCAST,NOARP> 
  # ls -l /sys/class/net/dummy9
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Apr  4 22:09 /sys/class/net/dummy9 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/dummy9
  ```

  Using a [lower level tool](https://manpages.debian.org/util-linux/unshare.1) to change to an other (ephemeral) network namespace:

  ```
  # unshare --net ip -br link show dummy9 
  Device "dummy9" does not exist.
  # unshare --net ls -l /sys/class/net/dummy9
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Apr  4 22:13 /sys/class/net/dummy9 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/dummy9
  ```

  And that's the issue: `/sys` still exposes initial host's interfaces instead of the new network namespace's interface. That's where there is an interaction between network namespace and with mounting `/sys`: if `/sys` is mounted from the new network namespace, it will switch to exposing the new network interfaces in select directory hierarchies (eg `/sys/class/net` and `/sys/devices/virtual/net`). This is done at mount time only, not dynamically. Some advanced network settings are easily available by just reading or writing there, so they have to be provided, and the reverse is true: the isolated processes running in the new network environment shouldn't be able to see or alter the initial host's interfaces.

So `ip netns exec FOO ...` (but not `ip netns add FOO`) solves this by also [unsharing](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/unshare.2) the *mount* namespace and remounting `/sys/` inside it, to not disrupt initial host's network namespace. But what is important is that this mount namespace is itself ephemeral: when you run separately two `ip netns exec FOO ...` commands, they don't end up in the same mount namespace. They each have their own, with `/sys` remounted there pointing to the same network namespace.

Until now, no problem. I'll call this an "ip netns namespace" when this happened since there are now two types of namespaces involved. We have so far:

term1:

```
# ip netns add FOO
# ls -l /proc/$$/ns/{mnt,net}
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Apr  4 22:28 /proc/1712/ns/mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Apr  4 22:28 /proc/1712/ns/net -> net:[4026531992]
# ip netns exec FOO bash
# ls -l /proc/$$/ns/{mnt,net}
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Apr  4 22:33 /proc/1864/ns/mnt -> mnt:[4026532618]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Apr  4 22:33 /proc/1864/ns/net -> net:[4026532520]
```

term2:

```
# ls -l /proc/$$/ns/{mnt,net}
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Apr  4 22:32 /proc/1761/ns/mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Apr  4 22:32 /proc/1761/ns/net -> net:[4026531992]
# ip netns exec FOO bash
# ls -l /proc/$$/ns/{mnt,net}
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Apr  4 22:33 /proc/1866/ns/mnt -> mnt:[4026532821]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Apr  4 22:33 /proc/1866/ns/net -> net:[4026532520]
```

Note how after changing ip netns namespaces, while the new network namespace is the same for *term1* and *term2*, the new mount namespaces are different from each others (and from initial host).

Now what happens when in *term1* you create a new ip netns namespace? Let's see:

term1:

```
# ip netns add BAR
# ip netns ls
BAR
FOO
```

term2:

```
# ip netns ls
Error: Peer netns reference is invalid.
Error: Peer netns reference is invalid.
BAR
FOO
```

That's because the newer namespace BAR, to be kept existing without a process, is, as others, *mounted* on (the newly created empty file) `/var/run/netns/BAR` (again, see [previous link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471122/namespace-management-with-ip-netns-iproute2/471214#471214) for examples). While the mount namespaces are different, they have the same root directory: initial host's root. So of course this newly created empty file `/var/run/netns/BAR` could be seen everywhere (initial, *term1*'s mount ns, *term2*'s mount ns) when it was created.

Alas, the mount over it, being done on *term1*'s FOO's mount namespace, can only be seen on *term1*, not on *term2* nor anywhere else, because it's a different mount namespace. So while in term1 ('s FOO ip netns namespace) `/var/run/netns/BAR` is a pseudo-file belonging to the `nsfs` pseudo-filesystem:

term1:

```
# stat -f -c %T /var/run/netns/BAR
nsfs
```

It's an empty file on `tmpfs` (from the actual `/run` mount) anywhere else:

term2:

```
# stat -f -c %T /var/run/netns/BAR
tmpfs
```

Any other terminal:

```
$ stat -f -c %T /var/run/netns/BAR
tmpfs
```

It can still be seen in term1 as long as one doesn't exit the current "ip netns namespace". If from *term1* one still switches ip netns namespaces , it will still be fine, because the new unshared ephemeral mount namespace is a copy of the previous, including all the mounts.

If exited, that mount point is lost (and that means if there are no processes or file descriptors using it anymore, BAR's corresponding network namespace will disappear because it was held only by this mount point). After this any `ip netns ls` command will complain, anywhere. You can just remove the stale and now useless file `/run/netns/BAR` to fix it.

After this step-by-step explanation, what to remember is that you shouldn't *create* new namespaces with `ip netns add` inside a namespace currently entered with `ip netns exec`. You should create them all from the initial (host) namespace, then you can switch at will between them from any ip netns namespace.

Of course, if `/var/run/netns/` (i.e. the mount point `/run`) is distinct between (staying fuzzy) namespaces, then there is no interaction, and each `ip netns` invocation will be isolated from others, not seing nor interacting with others. Where does this usually happen? In full containers, where both the mount and the network namespaces are separated and point to distinct resources from the start.

---

**UPDATE**: as asked in comments, I checked how to "repair" this problem, but couldn't find any easy solution.

First there's a prerequisite: as told above, once the new "ip netns" namespace BAR is created inside FOO, and FOO is left, the only reference to BAR will disappear, thus making BAR also disappear. Something more is needed.

Actually there are three ways to keep a [reference to a namespace](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/namespaces.7#The_/proc/%5Bpid%5D/ns/_directory):

- process: that's the main method, and most of the time that's how the namespace is used at all
- mount point (that's the method used by `ip netns`): allows to keep a namespace without any process, fine to have a namespace with only network settings inside (interfaces, bridges, tc rules, firewall rules, ...)
- open file descriptor: rare, used when creating the namespaces, but seldom kept, except for applications dealing with multiple namespaces at the same time and switching some of their threads using the file descriptor for easy reference.

We can use the 1st or 3rd method. Here are various failed attempts before finding something that works...

As told before, won't work:

```
# ip netns add FOO
# ip netns exec FOO ip netns add BAR
```

Just leave a process running temporarily in the *first* "ip netns" namespace, for its ephemeral *mount* namespace part, to keep the needed reference to the *new* "ip netns" namespace's *network* namespace and reuse it later from outside (from the initial namespace).

Won't work either:

```
# ip netns add FOO
# ip netns exec FOO sh -c 'ip netns add BAR; sleep 999 < /var/run/netns/BAR & echo $!'
28344
# strace -e trace=readlink,mount mount --bind /proc/6295/fd/0 /var/run/netns/BAR
readlink("/proc/6295/fd/0", "/run/netns/BAR", 4095) = 14
readlink("/var/run", "/run", 4095)      = 4
mount("/run/netns/BAR", "/run/netns/BAR", 0x55c88c9cccb0, MS_BIND, NULL) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
# stat -f -c %T /run/netns/BAR
tmpfs
```

As seen with `strace` the `mount` command followed the symlink when it shouldn't have for this use case (note: the mount is still linked to the sleep process somehow which has to be killed to unmount it).

This (entering `sleep`'s *mount* namespace, to access the BAR's mounted *network* namespace hidden there) works but relies on the continued existence of `sleep` or any process for continued use:

```
# ip netns add FOO
# ip netns exec FOO sh -c 'ip netns add BAR; ip -n BAR link add dummy8 type dummy; sleep 999 & echo $!'
12916
# nsenter --target=12916 --mount ip -n -brief BAR link show
lo               DOWN           00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK> 
dummy8           DOWN           8e:ce:b3:d1:9c:bb <BROADCAST,NOARP>
```

strangely this (using the mount namespace shortcut [`/proc/pid/root/`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt#L141)) doesn't work (I don't really know why):

```
# stat -f -c %T /proc/12916/root/var/run/netns/BAR 
tmpfs
```

Finally what will work:

```
# ip netns add FOO
# ip netns exec FOO sh -c 'ip netns add BAR; ip -n BAR link add dummy8 type dummy; ip netns exec BAR sh -c '\''sleep 999 & echo $!'\'
14124
# mount --bind /proc/14124/ns/net /var/run/netns/BAR
# ip -n BAR -brief link show
lo               DOWN           00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK> 
dummy8           DOWN           3a:48:65:20:68:c1 <BROADCAST,NOARP>
```

So something like this could be used in the end. There might be race conditions if you attempt to delete them right after, before the sleep command ends.

```
# ip netns add FOO
# mount --bind /proc/$(ip netns exec FOO sh -c 'ip netns add BAR; ip netns exec BAR bash -c '\''sleep 5 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!; disown'\')/ns/net /var/run/netns/BAR
```

How could such a construct be used? I have no idea because the original problem before encountering the nested "ip netns" problem was not given. Maybe easier solutions are available without ever trying to create "a nested network namespace".

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Is there a way to create a new netns safely while inside a netfs. i.e ip netfs exec foo1 /bin/bash.... ip netns exec <something> ip netns add foo2?

Comment: It appears much more difficult than it seemed, and I don't see how to use the result in an actual use case. Perhaps you should ask an other question, about the *original* problem which forced you to try creating "nested network namespaces". Anyway I'm updating the answer.

Comment: The original problem was to make openvpn move the tun interface into a new namespace. This way one could make a namespace with just two interfaces (lo and tun0) that is VPN'd without altering the global network stack. Creating nested namespaces would be convenient to create a system for: localhost -> vpn1 -> vpn2 -> public internet. It actually does in fact work this way, except the only inconvenience is the "invalid peer netns" error messages. See https://github.com/conallprendergast/openvpn-netns-systemd for the implementation

Comment: As long as you have a references on those namespaces it's easy later to "repair" this issue in initial host. So here I'm assuming openvpn is running in a net namespace. something like `mount --bind /proc/$(pidof openvpn)/ns/net /var/run/netns/somenamespace` . The question didn't show any process launched.